# cv::convertTo() function

Tags: c++, opencv

I am following the examples from the book "Learning OpenCV 3 Computer Vision in C++ with the OpenCV Library" and the following piece from Example 12-1 puzzles me:

```
A.convertTo(dft_A_part, dft_A_part.type(), 1, -mean(A)[0]);
```

as a result of this operation I was expecting the values of `A` being copied to `dft_A_part` after subtracting the value `mean(A)[0]` from each.

Not the case, hence my confusion.

`A` is `cv::Mat (CV_8U)`

`dft_A_part` is `cv::Mat (CV_32_F)`

Some observed values:

mean(A)[0] = 88.65

A.data[0] = 77, dft_A_part.data[0] = 136.0

A.data[1] = 77, dft_A_part.data[1] = 140.0

A.data[2] = 79, dft_A_part.data[2] = 58.0

I understand that there is `saturation_cast<>` being applied in `cv::convertTo()` but how could that result in these numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dft_A_part.data` is a pointer to `uchar`, and the type of `dft_A_part` is `float`.

`dft_A_part.data[0]`, `dft_A_part.data[1]`, `dft_A_part.data[2]` represents the first, second and third bytes of a `float` element.

The value of the `float` element in memory is `-11.65f`.
The float element is stored as 4 bytes in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) format.
The values we are getting here are meaningless (just part of the mantissa).

Note that `dft_A_part.data[0]` = `136` and not `136.0`...

---

Instead of using `dft_A_part.data[0]`, we may use: `dft_A_part.at<float>(0, 0)`.

We may also cast `data` to float pointer: `float *data_as_float = (float*)dft_A_part.data;`

---

Code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main()
{
    const double meanA = 88.65; // Assume mean(A)[0] equals 88.65

    cv::Mat A = cv::Mat(1, 3, CV_8UC1); // Create new matrix with 1 row, 3 columns of type uchar.
    A.at<uchar>(0, 0) = 77;
    A.at<uchar>(0, 1) = 77;
    A.at<uchar>(0, 2) = 79;

    cv::Mat dft_A_part = cv::Mat(1, 3, CV_32FC1); //Create new matrix with 1 row, 3 columns of type float.

    A.convertTo(dft_A_part, dft_A_part.type(), 1, -meanA);  //Convert A to float and add -88.65

    //data[0], data[1], data[2] are meaningless
    //std::cout << "dft_A_part.data[0] = " << std::to_string(dft_A_part.data[0]) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "dft_A_part.data[1] = " << std::to_string(dft_A_part.data[1]) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "dft_A_part.data[2] = " << std::to_string(dft_A_part.data[2]) << std::endl;

    //Print 3 elements using .at function:
    std::cout << "dft_A_part.at<float>(0, 0) = " << std::to_string(dft_A_part.at<float>(0, 0)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dft_A_part.at<float>(0, 1) = " << std::to_string(dft_A_part.at<float>(0, 1)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dft_A_part.at<float>(0, 2) = " << std::to_string(dft_A_part.at<float>(0, 2)) << std::endl << std::endl; 

    //Print 3 elements using casting data to float pointer:
    float *data_as_float = (float*)dft_A_part.data;
    std::cout << "data_as_float[0] = " << std::to_string(data_as_float[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "data_as_float[1] = " << std::to_string(data_as_float[1]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "data_as_float[2] = " << std::to_string(data_as_float[2]) << std::endl;
}
```

---

Output:

```
dft_A_part.at<float>(0, 0) = -11.650002
dft_A_part.at<float>(0, 1) = -11.650002
dft_A_part.at<float>(0, 2) = -9.650002

data_as_float[0] = -11.650002
data_as_float[1] = -11.650002
data_as_float[2] = -9.650002
```

As we can see, the data casting to float is performed before adding the offset (`saturation_cast` is not used).